# Is there a class of recurrence relations that can't be solved using the substitution method?

Tags: recurrence-relation

Is there a class of recurrence relations that can't be solved using the substitution method? Let me explain the motivation behind this question by an example.

Consider the recurrence relation $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$. It's obvious that $T$ is in $\Theta(n \log n)$.

To verify that $T(n)$ is in $O(n\log n)$, one could use the substitution method and the inductive hypotheses $T(n) ≤ cn\log n + d$, where $d$ is to be replaced by term of lower order.

Inductive step:

$$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n ≤ 2(cn\log n + d) = 2cn\log(n/2) + 2d + n = cn\log n + \ell d + n,$$ where $\ell = 2$.

As $\ell > 1$ holds, one can choose $(\ell-1)d := -n$. As a result, the last term $n$ vanishes in the next step:

$$cn\log n + \ell d + n = cn\log n + d$$

Choosing $c$ properly for the the given $d$ should complete this proof. However, this approach sometimes fails if $\ell$ equals 1.

This is illustrated by the following example, where the goal is to prove a lower bound:

$$T(n) = T(n - 2) + n^2$$

Hypothesis: $T(n - 2) ≥ cn^3 + d$ for all $n' ≤ n$:

$$T(n + 1) = T(n - 1) + (n-1)^3 ≥ c(n-1)^3 + d + n^2$$

I would be very thankful for an explanation.

Comment: It is very confusing to use $d$ for a function that depends on $n$. Using $d(n)$ instead is recommended.

Comment: There's absolutely no problem proving the formula for $T(n)$ in your second example by induction. In fact, it's the kind of exercise given in courses on discrete mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for your ans. Could you please add a hint how to prove this?

Comment: Find the formula by summing the series, then prove it by induction.